# How can we calculate effective megapixel loss due to diffraction?

Tags: aperture, light, sensor-size, physics, diffraction

How can we calculate an image's *effective* megapixel count at each aperture setting, specifically as loss relates to diffraction?

Assume that we already know the sensor size, its true megapixel count, and assume that the camera is paired with a perfect lens.

Comment: What is mega pixel loss? What is a perfect lens,  is that a thing,  do they exist ?

Comment: What's an "effective megapixel"?

Comment: Not an answer, because it doesn't involve megapixels, but take a look at Wikipedia's entry on "Optical resolution" especially the "System resolution" section.

Comment: You might look at DxOMark's lens evaluations to see how they construct a MP rating for a given lens-camera combo.  In real world shooting the diffraction limit is the least of my concerns trying to get what I need in reasonable focus.

Comment: "Effective megapixel" is an invented single number way to rate a lens. It was invented not because lenses lend themselves to single number score comparisons, but rather because consumers want single number scores to either decide which thing is "better" than the other thing to to brag that their thing is "better" than someone else's thing.

Answer (score 2):

Maximum recordable resolution based on sensor size and aperture (diffraction); for blue/green/red wavelengths (green being most important).

The sensor's resolution is (mostly) irrelevant unless it is less than the diffraction imposed limit. And a perfect lens doesn't matter if it resolves to a resolution greater than the sensor's capability.

[image: maximum recordable resolution]

Taken from [this paper](https://www2.uned.es/personal/rosuna/resources/photography/Diffraction/Do%20sensors%20outresolve.pdf)